# problem in reading binary file (mix of ascii and binary)

Tags: c++, file-io

My code for reading binary file is:

```
dataFile.open(fileName.c_str());
ifstream binData("Trafficlog_Data.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);  //binary data file 
if(!binData) { 
  cout << "Cannot open file.\n"; 
  return -1; 
} 
char *memblock;int nBytes =12;
memblock = new char [nBytes+1];
binData.read(memblock,nBytes);
memblock[nBytes+1]='\0';
std::string message;message.assign(memblock,nBytes);
printf("%s\n",message.c_str());
```

Now i have given a file as input which contain binary and ascii data
RFB 003.003
RFB 003.003
--some binary data--

When I am reading first 12 bytes of file which is "RFB 003.003\n" but it prints "RFB 003.003=". Can anyone tell where i m getting it wrong please.
promblem is not with '\0'. problem is it is not reading "RFB 003.003\n" . IS it because this file is mix of binary and ascii data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
memblock[nBytes+1]='\0';
```

to:

```
memblock[nBytes]='\0';
```

Let's say you read in six bytes to `memblock`, that goes into positions `0` through `5` inclusive:

```
  0   1   2   3   4   5    6    7
+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+
| H | E | L | L | O | \n | ? | ? |
+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+
```

(the `?` areas still contain whatever rubbish was there before).

You then need to put the null terminator at position 6 rather than position 7 as your code is doing.

By placing the null terminator too far to the "right", you're including that first `?` position, which could be holding anything.

---

That's what's causing your specific problem. You also have an issue that you're not allocating space to hold the data you're reading in. You just have a `char *` but you're not actually initialising it to point to usable memory. That's almost certainly going to cause problems.

Probably the simplest solution is to define it as:

```
char memblock[nBytes+1];
```

Although I see you've fixed that in your question now so it's of little consequence. The *actual* problem (putting the null byte at the wrong location) is covered above.

Comment: You also need to consider the case where you hit EOF before your `nBytes` elements have been read (check the stream's eofbit).  In that case you'll have to figure out how many bytes were actually read.

Comment: @honeybadger: that doesn't really matter. Whatever you're reading, you have to put the null terminator at the right place. However, I adjusted the answer to make it closer to your desired scenario.

Comment: i have put '\0' at right place. just after i read 12 bytes i.e "RFB 003.003\n" and put '\0' after that but what is actually read from file is "RFB 003.003=" problem is with mix of ascii and binary data i guess

Comment: @honeybadger, you need to re-read the answer. You read 12 bytes (offsets 0 thru 11) then you put the null at offset `nBytes+1` - that's _13,_ not 12 as it should be. Whatever rubbish was at offset 12 before you started is still there.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't allocate memory for memblock:

```
char *memblock = new char[nBytes+1];
```

Comment: Hehe, +1, totally missed that one.

Comment: i did that but didnt wrote it here . sry

Answer (score 0):

You're off-by-one: just do `memblock[nBytes]='\0';` The index starts at 0, so if `nBytes` is 0 you're writing at the first position, if `nBytes` is 1 you're writing at the second position and so on. By doing `nBytes + 1` you actually jumped ahead one position and left one garbage byte at the end of the string.